# Android Room DAO - should we use LiveData in case of both Lifecycle aware/non aware observers

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, android-jetpack, kotlin-coroutines

Should we use LiveData as a return result from Query function in DAO interface when:

- we want to use this function in ViewModel (Lifecycle-aware)
- we want to use this function in DB initializer (non-lifecycle aware)
- we want to use it in some kind of background processing callbacks (non-lifecycle aware)

What is the best practice here? Should we use coroutines and convert to LiveData? Should we use rx? Or maybe just create 2 functions with different return result type?

Answer (score 1):

LiveData should be used only with a lifecycle and only to update ui. The LiveData observer is called always in the main thread. If you want to execute other code you should use a Flow as a return type of Query function. With Flow you can specify the coroutines dispatcher that execute the code and you can convert it into a LiveData with this function:

```
liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    myFlow.collect {
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

Also you can create two different methods.